# CSS div design nth-child

Tags: html, css

I have a website design.

[image: design]

I attached the file of what it looks like. In the boxes there will be data from a MySQL database.

My question is, is it possible to make it with only one query?

I can do it by making a query with limit 2 for the first 2 boxes and again a limit with the 3rd and 4th boxes and a 3rd query for rest of the boxes.

But I am thinking that it is possible to make it with CSS that the first and second boxes have a design and the 3rd and 4th boxes have an other design and for the rest there is an other design. So it will be like a div will be generated automatically but depends on the number of divs, then apply other design.

Comment: You seem to already know that the nth-child selector exists - so what is your specific question here …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for this. You can try this code. It is fully tested. I hope it will help you.

**HTML:**

```
<div>test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
<div>test4</div>
<div>test5</div>
<div>test6</div>
<div>test7</div>
<div>test8</div>
<div>test9</div>
<div>test10</div>
<div>test11</div>
<div>test12</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
}
div:nth-child(1), div:nth-child(2){
    width: 100%;
}
div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(4){
    width: 50%;
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any css rule you write will have to be algebraically expressed.

**an+b-1**

To be clear, there can be no logic passed from HTML/DOM to CSS, unless you use JS.

However, you can get pretty complex using :nth-child() and :nth-last-child() in concert.

[MDN :nth-Child refrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

It sounds like what you're looking for would be something like:

```
div{
    width: 25%
}
div:nth-of-type(1), div:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 100%;
}
div:nth-of-type(3), div:nth-of-type(4){
    width: 50%;
}
```